# Prove an inequality involving trigonometric series

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, trigonometric-series

I am reading a proof, in which there is an inequality that I cannot prove.

Let $\{\phi_n\}$ be a sequence of reals. Let $N$ be an integer $\ge 2$.

Let $p(t)=\sum_{n=0}^N b_n \cos(nt+\phi_n)$.

**Desired inequality:** $b_n \le 4/\pi \| p\|_\infty$.

I don't even know where the $4/\pi$ comes from...

Also, some of the summands can positive and some of them can be negative. How can one use the $L^\infty$ bound to derive such an inequality?

Thanks for help.

---

Edit: Added the entire proof.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could help you, but I personally need to see the whole proof

Comment: You may multiply both sides by $\cos(nt + \phi_n)$ so as to apply $\cos(A) \cos(B) =  \frac12 (\cos(A-B)+\cos(A-B) )$ to make the coefficient in front of $b_n$ has a $1$. Then you make use the fact that if $\cos(jt + \phi_j)$ ($j\neq 0$), then its integral between $0$ and $2\pi$ will be zero.

Comment: @MaximusFastidiousIrreverence Have added the whole proof.

Comment: @Sisi We need  being integer to have $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(jt + \phi_j) dt$ for $j \neq 0$, right? (Luckily $j$ must be integer here)

Comment: Is there some information missing? If $b_1 = b_2 = \cdots = 0$ then $p(t) = b_0 \cos(\phi_0)$, and the desired inequality $b_n \le 4/\pi \| p\|_\infty$ does not hold if $\phi_0$ is close to $\pi/2$.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry for the late reply. Your counterexample missed the condition that $N\ge 2$. There is no further information on the assumption of the propositition.

Comment: $p(t) = b_0 \cos(\phi_0) + 0 \cdot \cos(t) + 0 \cdot \cos(2t)$ is of the given form with $N=2$ and $b_1 = b_2 = 0$. Perhaps you want to require that $b_N \ne 0$?

Comment: @MartinR Yea I guess it is an implicit condition that $b_N \neq 0$. Otherwise it is meaningless to require $N\ge 2$.